# Drag from NSCollectionView to NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview, nscollectionview

OK, here's is what I want to do :

- I have an `NSCollectionView` filled with items
- I have an `NSOutlineView` (a "tree" structure actually)
- I want to be able to drag any item from the `NSCollectionView` and drop it on an `NSOutlineView` item, and depending on what the item is, highlight it, and "accept" the operation.

Any guidelines? I've handled drag'n'drop in the past, but in a simpler situation.

How should I go about it in the most Cocoa-friendly way?

Answer (score 0):

OK, although I've not yet figured the whole thing out, I'll start by answering with what's working so far - and keep editing it.

**Step 1 : *Make the NSOutlineView draggable***

In `NSCollectionView`'s delegate, implement :

```
-(BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView 
canDragItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes 
            withEvent:(NSEvent*)event
{
      return YES;
}


- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView 
   writeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes 
          toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard
{
      return YES;
}
```